# Is there a Python module to "thaw" data frozen using Perl's Storable?

Tags: python, perl, serialization

I have a legacy database which contains simple data structures (no CODE refs thank goodness) that have been written using the `nfreeze` method of the [`Storable`](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable/Storable.pm) module in Perl.

Now I have a need to load this data into a Python application. Does anyone know of a Python implementation of `Storable`'s `thaw`? Google hasn't helped me.

If it comes to it, I can reverse engineer the data format from the [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable/Storable.pm) source, but I'd prefer to avoid that fun if it's been done already.

To express in code: Given a Perl program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;
use Storable qw/nfreeze/;

my $data = {
    'string' => 'something',
    'arrayref' => [1, 2, 'three'],
    'hashref' => {
        'a' => 'b',
    },
};

print encode_base64( nfreeze($data) );
```

I'm after a `magic_function` such that this Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import base64
import pprint
import sys

def magic_function(frozen):
    # A miracle happens
    return thawed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frozen = base64.b64decode(sys.stdin.read())
    data = magic_function(frozen)
    pprint.pprint(data)
```

prints:

```
{'string': 'something', 'arrayref': [1, 2, 'three'], 'hashref': {'a': 'b'}}
```

when run against the output of the Perl program.

Comment: Storable tries to store as much data as possible to exactly restore the stored Perl structure. If the data crosses language boundaries, you probably don't need that level of detail. JSON would be faster and probably less painful.

Comment: Absolutely. If I was writing this from scratch I'd use a language agnostic serialisation format such as JSON. But I'm not. There is far too much legacy Perl code that both reads and writes the data using `Storable` for me to change it now without risk of major regressions. Much safer to find some way to read these values from the new Python code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not immediately clear to me how far along this project is, but it appears to aim to do what you want:

https://pypi.org/project/storable/

Comment: Wow thanks. How did I miss that? Will give it a go and report back on its suitability

Answer (score 6):

If your first option doesn't work, another option would be to write a simple perl script to thaw the data, and then write it out in JSON or YAML or some format that you can easily work with in Python.

Comment: Would have been a good KISS solution that could have been optimised later. But as python-storable seems to work, I can jump straight to the optimised solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Was thinking of the same but with `YAML`.

Comment: @Dallaylaen: Doesn't really matter which format (even XML), but updated anyway :-) And like ikegami says in the OP comments, JSON (the XS version) is even faster than Storable in the first place, so if possible, it ought to be replaced in the original perl process.